# System cannot Load Native Library mvm.dll

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab

I am working on Calling matlab function in java code by using Java Matlab Engine API in Eclipse.
I have written very simple program but its giving me runtime error.
I have written this code:

```
 import com.mathworks.engine.*;
 import com.mathworks.*;


  public class Matlab_main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception
    {

     MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab();
     eng.evalAsync("disp('hello world')");
      eng.close();

     } }
```

I have done the following steps:

- I have added engine.jar file in its library build path .
- I have also set its java.library.path = "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a    \bin\win64"  by going into its Native Library settings.
- I have also added this entry  C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64    to PATH environment variables

But its giving me error that System cannot Load Native Library mvm.dll

This dll is present in this directory C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64,but eclipse is not finding that.

I am totally stuck, Please kindly help me

Comment: There is an extra space in the `java.library.path` setting here: ...13a \bin\... did this happen only when you wrote it into the question?